# How do I find the equation of a curve that is derived?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have a test in a few days. I can't figure out this question:

If ${d^2y\over dx^2} = 6x+6 $, and there is a stationary point at $(0,3)$, find the equation on the cure.

The Answer is $y=x^3+3x^2+3$

Its a year 12 geometric applications calculus topic. I looked through all the examples in the textbook and found nothing, and I'm clueless.

-Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

So integrating w.r.t $x$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2+6x+C$. Applying the stationary point we get $C=0$. Integrating one more time we have $y=x^3+3x^2+D$ and this curve satisfy the point $(0,3)$, so $D=3$.